# Override default.phtml not working

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I am trying to override "vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\shipment\items\renderer\default.phtml" in my module.

I have copied vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_shipment_renderers.xml in my module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="sales.order.shipment.renderers">
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="Vendor_Module::order/shipment/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

also I have copied the default.phtml in my module still not working.

Any suggestion where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

   <referenceBlock name="sales.order.shipment.renderers">

       <action method="setTemplate">

           <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Name_Space]_[Your_Module]::default.phtml</argument>

       </action>

   </referenceBlock>

</page>
```

- [Name_Space]_[Your_Module]::default.phtml : is a template file of your module.
- Create checkout_cart.phtml file in

`app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/view/frontend/templates/order/shipment/items/renderer/default.phtml`

Comment: I tried this but still its not showing any result. One more thing I am working on sales-sales module then why do I have to create checkout_cart.phtml file?